# Question about the claws of the Path of the Beast UA

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, barbarian, two-weapon-fighting, natural-weapon

So my question is about the UA subclass for Barbarian, The Path of the Beast.

The question is when I choose the claws option, both of my hands become natural weapons (Cause ya know, claws). So in this case can I make an off-hand strike with the claw with a bonus action? If yes then is it d6+str+rage or just d6+rage? If it is the latter then can I take the dual wield fighting style and add the str bonus to the bonus action offhand attack?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing exactly the answer given on that question.

Comment: Might be worth a specific answer here as the feature in question has an additional attack built-in, likely to compensate for the inability to use two-weapon fighting?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that, despite being "natural weapons" in the English sense, the claws granted by this feature are not "Natural Weapons" in the sense of game terms. In the absence of a specific rule saying otherwise, the general rule says that these would still just be unarmed strikes so you can't make the bonus action attack unless you're also a monk.